# log4j error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getTimestamp()J

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I am using **log4j -1.2.13**, **slf4j-api-1.7.15 jar** ,**slf4j-nop-1.7.15** jar with *java 11* ,tomcat 9 versions.
I am getting below 2 errors

1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getTimestamp()J
2. unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.asyc.AsyncLoggerConfig for element AsyncLogger: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com/lmax/disruptor/EventFactory  java.lang.reflect.InvocationException

Comment: You must have other logging dependencies in your project (probably `slf4j-log4j12`, `log4j-core`?).  If you are using Gradle or Maven, please add all your project dependencies to your question. Otherwise look for other libraries with names starting with `log4j`, `slf4j`, `commons-logging`, `logback`, ...

Comment: iI am using Maven with commons-logging , slf4j, lo4j jars.

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67674415/edit) you questions and add the contents of your `pom.xml` file: there might be some transitive dependencies, which cause these problems.

Comment: we are not directly adding dependencies in pom.xml, from repo we are downloading jars into maven and building war again and giving build and then deploying.

Comment: issue is in ecs environment.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an inconsistent set of logging libraries:

1. `LoggingEvent#getTimestamp` was introduced in `log4j-1.2.15`, so you just have to upgrade your library.
2. `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.asyc.AsyncLoggerConfig` is a class from Log4j 2.x, which means you have at least two version of Log4j on your classpath. The error is caused by your configuration file which uses the non-existent `com/lmax/disruptor/EventFactory` class.

Comment: I have only 1version of log4j-1.2.13.